# optimizing 3D in free roaming games

Tags: optimization, 3d, theory

I've begun looking into 3D game development and I want to create  something with an open world.
The problem that I anticipate having is that backdrop landscaping such as mountains and city skylines will get really straining performance-wise since the open-world implies you can actually visit them (plus, as a designer I don't like putting up invisible walls everywhere to break the immersion.)

A solution I've been able to come up with is creating a high- medium- and low-detail version of pieces of landscape and render them in a particular fashion depending on how far away the player is.

However, are there any better ways to take care of this problem? I wouldn't exactly like to have three of each resource (if not more) in order to make my game run smoothly.

Comment: Have you *really* not heard of [level of detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail)?

Comment: I've been looking for something like that without success. As I said, I've only just begun looking into it. I'll take a look at it right now.